# Connecting with SQL database using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, sqlconnection

I'm wondering if someone could help me with this issue. I'm trying to connect to a SQL database using cypress but it keep displaying an error message. I'm using following:

Cypress 3.6.1

NodeJs 12.13.0

npm 6.12.0

Package.json has following dependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
 "cypress": "^3.6.0",
 "cypress-sql-server": "^1.0.0"
  },
 "dependencies": {
 "tedious": "^6.6.2"
  }
```

Cypress.json has DB credentials in following format:

```
"env": {
"db": { 
"username": "", "password": "", "server": "localhost",
"options": { "database": "", "encrypt": true, "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true } 
 }
}
```

Plugin initialised in cypress\plugins\index.js file:

```
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');    
module.exports = (on, config) => {
tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config.env.db);
on('task', tasks); 
}
```

Command imported in cypress\support\index.js file:

```
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server';
sqlServer.loadDBCommands();
```

Spec file has following test:

```
cy.sqlServer('SELECT * FROM test');
```

Cypress shows following error:

```
CypressError: cy.task('sqlServer:execute') failed with the following error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost\MSSQLSERVER:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
localhost\MSSQLSERVER
at ConnectionError (C:\CypressTest\node_modules\cypress-sql- 
server\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
at Connection.socketError (C:\CypressTest\node_modules\cypress-sql- 
server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1008:28)
at C:\CypressTest\node_modules\cypress-sql-server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:874:21
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (C:\CypressTest\node_modules\cypress-sql- 
server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:48:16)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:70:17)
```

Comment: Make sure that your sql server is listening on `localhost:1433`

Answer (score 0):

The attempt to resolve "localhost\MSSQLSERVER" as either an IPv4 or IPv6 address has failed.

Open SQL Server Management Studio and the window title will tell you the exact machine name. Let's say, it's "DEV123", then in your server settings, instead of:

```
"server":"localhost"
```

use:

```
"server":"localhost\\DEV123"
```